# Simple interactive html lists with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

My programming knowledge is very limited so I would really appreciate any help on this. Lets say I have an ordered nested .html list like this:

1. A
2. B

   1. D
   2. E

      1. F
      2. G
3. C

Now I already have a script to make these items appear sequentially by using the up/down keyboard arrows:

```
var curIndex = 0;
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 38) {
        if(curIndex > 0) curIndex--;
        $("li").eq(curIndex).hide();
    }
    else if(e.keyCode === 40) {
        $("li").eq(curIndex).show();
        if(curIndex < 3) curIndex++; 
    }
});
```

What I would like to achieve is to have the same functionality, but only for a specific nested level. So at the beginning it would open "A-B-C". Then if you activate the "B" level for example by a mouseclick it would work for "D-E". If you click on the "E" for "F-G".

I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$('li')`, which grabs all the LI tags in the document.

You could use `$('#ul_id li')` to grab just the LI tags inside a specific list `<ul id="ul_id">`.

Or use `$('li').not(':hidden')` to get a list of only visible LI tags.

Comment: Thx for your response! I am using my script on .html files that are structured like: "<ul class="itemize1"> <li class="itemize">A" but "<ul class="itemize2"> <li class="itemize">D". Does your way still work? Or would I somehow need to grab only the li from the itemize class of itemiz1 or itemize2 if I only want to access this nesting level?

Comment: Without a more complete sample of your code, it's hard for me to say for sure. Why not just try it and see what happens?